# Magento 2 - Replace the Toplinks HTML class "Link"

Tags: magento2

How can I replace the HTML Class of the top links block? I thought I can do it by overriding this class https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Html/Links.php

But not sure if it is the right thing to do, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can add class using argument

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">custom_class</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

To add the class to link, for example I've added **custom-class** to registration link as below in `default.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">custom-class</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: That is the main one, what I am trying to change is the inner links i.e login, it has links class, I want to change that for example.

Comment: The `links` class you saw is in the template, so you need to overwrite template to get what you want, the `Html/Links` can't help it

Comment: @IbrahimS I've updated my answer, please check it will help you.